# Scanner(JTextfield) rather than Scanner(System.in)

Tags: java, swing, stream

I wan to have an inputStream that takes the value of a JTextbox and passes it into the Scanner object.

```
       Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("New Match")) {
            try {
                newMatch(scan);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("failed to load");
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {

            }
        }
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Load Match 1") || input.matches("1")){
            try {
                loadMatch(scan, "One");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("failed to load");
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ and this feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you want to do whatever it is you're trying to do?

Comment: "Sorry if my question is a bit confusing." -- don't apologize, but rather "un-confuse" the question by showing your [mcve] code and by making it much more concrete.

Comment: Added a small snippet of the code. @D.B. Thanks for downvoting and not helping. Hope someone will help in here.

Comment: I'm sorry you're under time constraints but that doesn't mean your question is easily understood or meets the guidelines of this site. I'm trying to help you create a better question that will be answerable. Attacking people who are trying to help you won't do you any good.

Comment: @D.B. I am not attacking but I think it is better to help a panicking person rather than giving him more stress by downvoting and telling him that his problem has more ambiguity than he imagines.

Comment: I'm with @D.B. and Don't know... I haven't a clue as to what problem you're trying to solve or what you're asking, so maybe they're right, maybe it's time to either improve this question so that it makes sense to others or else delete it. ... and I consider myself fairly knowledgeable in Swing too.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement - what problem are you trying to solve?  How would you handle backspaces or inserts? There are some many edge cases which would make it break it boggles the mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I interpret your question is that you have some existing code that is built on reading user input through an instance of `Scanner`. I *think* you're asking whether you can pull the text from a `JTextField` and push that into the instance of `Scanner` that is already used.

If the above understanding is correct and your `Scanner` instance is reading from `System.in` as it is in the code sample then my answer is no, you can't do *exactly* what you want.

However, you can get somewhat close to what you want.

Here is some code that creates a new `Scanner` each time the `actionPerformed` method is called and pushes data from a `JTextField` into that `Scanner` by simply passing the text from the text field into the scanner's constructor.

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    scanner.close(); //Don't forget to close your scanner before you reassign it
    String data = jTextField1.getText();        
    scanner = new Scanner(data);
    //Just to illustrate the results I added a println here
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());               
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not so sure as he mentioned something about an "InputStream", making me wonder if he is trying to redirect standard I/O. Well, we'll see what the OP says.

Comment: Also I don't agree with your ActionPerformed closing the Scanner. The code block that opened it should be the one responsible for closing it.

Comment: I agree that generally the opening block should close it but I get the impression the scanner is in a higher/larger scope and should remain open so that it can be used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Then he should use a new Scanner object attached to a method-*local* variable. Methods with such side effects can have unintended bad consequences.

Comment: It sounded to me like the scanner was being used as the vehicle to pass user input around, which I don't like but given the OP wants to minimize the impact of changes I tried to leave that part alone. There are definite opportunities for improvement/refactoring here no doubt about it.

Comment: I have tried this sir, you got it right but the problem it works only with the first line then it doesn't work. And another thing can the System.in be a custom inputstream that I set rather than the console?

Comment: @CptPackage: you do understand that `System.in` does not == console, that it instead means the standard input for that class. That **may** be the console, or it may be something else entirely, depending on how and where the object was created.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, but the problem is that the only consistent Scanner that gets created is the one on the files and System.in other things don't work well enough for me. And those working two aren't good enough to get the job done. Anyway sir, basically rather than having to write the code from scretch with actionlisteners as I have no time, so the only way is to get the scanner getting the data from the JTextfield in my gui rather than changing everything to work with the listeners.

Comment: Thanks in the end this fixed the issue, not the best performance as you said but worked in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `PipedOutputStream` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html)) and a `PipedInputStream` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html)) to create a one-way pipeline which you can then use to route input from a text field into a `Scanner`.  But you'll still have to figure out how to capture all the output that's going to `System.out` and display it to your GUI, nicely interwoven with the "echoed" input that came from your text field.

For what it's worth, though, I'll share a little proof-of-concept of half the solution.  This program reads "commands" from a `JTextField` through a `Scanner` and produces simulated "responses" to them; a `JTextArea` keeps a record of the simulated "conversation".  The input "commands" are logged automatically to the `JTextArea`, much as input from `System.in` would automatically echo to `System.out`, and I also explicitly echo them to `System.out`.  However, my simulated "responses" go not to `System.out` but directly to the JTextArea`.

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PipeTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public PipedInputStream pi; 
    private PipedOutputStream po;

    public PipeTest()
    {
        try {
            pi = new PipedInputStream();      // You write data into this end...
            po = new PipedOutputStream(pi);   // ,,, and read it back out at this end.
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Failed to initialize pipe: " + ioe.toString());
        }
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents()
    {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        historyText = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        historyText.setColumns(20);
        historyText.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(historyText);

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 369, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 220, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                            
    {                                                
        JTextField tf = (JTextField) evt.getSource();
        String text = tf.getText();
        byte[] ca = (text + System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes();
        try {
            po.write(ca, 0, ca.length);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to write to pipe: " + ex.toString());
        }
        historyText.append(text + "\n");
        tf.setText("");
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        PipeTest pt = new PipeTest();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            pt.setVisible(true);
        });
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(pt.pi);
        while (scn.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scn.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
            {
                pt.historyText.append("Response to " + line + "\n");
            });
        }
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea historyText;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Thanks but used the Scanner answer as it was more flexible for my deadline. The pipedStreams are better with performance but gave me some issues as it has to be on multiple threads.